# How to say "to ride a bicycle"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is it 自転車に乗る or　自転車を走る? I know I've read the latter somewhere before. But I just came across the former today and didn't know if there was a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure if this suits your needs, but `自転車を[漕]{こ}ぐ`, to pedal a bicycle, is frequently used.

Answer (score 4):

自転車を走る sound ungrammatical, you could say 自転車で道を走る or something like that, but I don't think 自転車を走る is correct Japanese.  自転車に乗る  is very common and means "ride a bicycle", as 乗る can also mean the action of "moving".